# Akka: Add custom serializer programmatically

Tags: scala, akka, serialization

Based on [Akka serialization documents](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/serialization.html), we can implement our own serializer and register it by configuration. Is it possible to register our own serializer programmatically (not by configuration), for example by the `ActorSystem` instance?

**UPDATE:**

Something like this:

```
ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("app");
actorSystem.registerSerializer(MySerializable.class, MyOwnSerializer());
```

instead of:

```
actor {
  serializers {
    custom = "x.y.z.MyOwnSerializer"
  }
  serialization-bindings {
    "x.y.z.MySerializable" = custom
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any explicit method to register the Custom Serializer. If so, they would have mentioned it in their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializers are created from config by querying `akka.actor.serializers`, so there is no direct option to override them using methods like `registerSerializer`.

What you can do instead, is programmatically create `Config` object and then pass it explicitly as the second parameter to `ActorSystem.create`. For example, you could do:

```
import com.typesafe.config._
//scala.collection.JavaConverters were deprecated in Scala 2.13
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._ 

val config = ConfigFactory.load() //load default values
     //override 'akka.actor.serializers'
     .withValue(
         "akka.actor.serializers", 
         ConfigValueFactory.fromMap(Map("hello" -> "x.y.z.MyOwnSerializer").asJava                   
     ).resolve()

val systemWithCustomConfig = ActorSystem.create("app", config)
```